# Where does Firestore Authentication keep user metadata?

Tags: firebase-authentication

When using Firestore Authentication, the only fields I see are "Identifier, Providers, Created, Signed In, User UID".

I can call the `getAuth()` function and get all the data for that user in a React page.

### Firebase.js

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  ...
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export firebaseApp
```

**What I'm curious about is I can call things like `user.displayName` but that metadata is not stored on Firebase (at least I don't know where if it is).**

### MyPage.js

```js
import { firebaseApp } from '../Firebase'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'

export default function MyPage() {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(getAuth())

  return <h1>Welcome to your account, {user.displayName}!</h1>
}
...
```

Can anyone please point out where this might be located?  I checked Storage in the same GCP project but there wasn't anything there.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact location (also that data is not shown in Firebase console) but what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just curious.  Practically I could never know and my web app will still function the same.